# Vue js - Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am implementing a search function with a search bar with Vue 2. I am using vuex also. I don't know what i am doing wrong but I have the error "Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')".

I have an elements.js file which stores the elements to search and it has the logic of the search function. Here it is:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const elementos = () => {
    return [{
        "plataforma": "android",
        "titulo": "Principios",
        "palabras_clave": "principios android accesibilidad",
        "texto":""
    },
{
    "plataforma": "android",
    "titulo": "Colores",
    "palabras_clave": "color mobil android",
    "texto":""}]
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        elementos: elementos(),
        filter: {
            query: '',
            plataforma: true 
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_QUERY (state, query){
            state.filter.query = query;
        },
        SET_PLATAFORMA (state){
            state.filter.plataforma = !state.filter.plataforma;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        filteredElements (state){
            let elem = state.elementos.filter(e => e.plataforma == state.filter.plataforma);
            if(state.filter.query.length > 2){
                return elem.filter(e => e.palabras_clave.toLowerCase().includes(state.filter.query))
            }
            return elem;
        }
    }
})
```

Then I have my component Principal.vue, where I have an input element that it has the property `v-model="search"`, and on the script tag I have the following:

```
<script>
import Menu from "../components/Menu.vue"
import Texto from "../components/Texto.vue"
import Nav from "../components/Nav.vue"

import elements from '../elements.js'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Menu,
    Texto,
    Nav
  },

  computed: {
    search: {
      get (){
        return this.$store.state.filter.query;
      },
      set (val){
        this.$store.commit('SET_QUERY', val);
      }
    }

  }
};

</script>
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

I am missing something but I don't know what can be. The error it says that the variable `query` is undefined, but I have imported the elements.js file, therefore it is supposed to exist.

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of the whole error? I want to see in which file is it throwing this error from.

Comment: It is edited now

Comment: it is throwing error because in the computed properties, while using get(), it finds no value assigned to query. It is trying to get the value query way before the value is being set.

Comment: I'm also not sure why have you placed your search logic in the vuex store. You can keep it simple by using the same logic in the watchers of the component.